# C# SQL INSERT INTO command doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have this code:

```
private void FirmaEkleB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO FIRMATABLE VALUES (@CompanyName)";

    SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, sqlconnection);

    Form1 LoginForm = new Form1();
    sqlconnection.Open();

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", FirmaIsmiTextbox.Text);
    command.ExecuteScalar();

    SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand("Select FirmaIsmi FROM FIRMATABLE WHERE ID = 9", sqlconnection);
    MessageBox.Show(com2.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    LoginForm.fillFirmaList();
}
```

`fillFirmaList()` looks like this:

```
public void fillFirmaList()
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM FirmaTable", connection);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

    DataTable firmaTable = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(firmaTable);

    FirmaCombo.DataSource = firmaTable;
    FirmaCombo.DisplayMember = "FirmaIsmi";
    FirmaCombo.ValueMember = "Id";
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I can't seem get my combobox to update from the table I have. The manually added rows show up but not the one that I add

Keep in mind that I'm just starting out in SQL Server and database stuff.

If more info is needed tell me.

Comment: Try adding with an explicit type instead of using `AddWithValue()`.

Comment: Always use Insert Column list in `Insert` statement. `INSERT INTO FIRMATABLE (CompanyName) VALUES (@CompanyName)`

Comment: Does your FIRMATABLE table only has 1 column?

Comment: it has an identity column and a company name column

Comment: change `command.ExecuteScalar();` to `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery() didnt change anything

Comment: @belkipAndroidness Your table has column called `FirmaIsmi` so even after fixing your current problem Insert query will throw error

Comment: Why? thats the column name? do i have to change the '@CompanyName' to '@FirmaIsmi'?

Comment: @belkipAndroidness - How many columns are present in `FIRMATABLE` table ?

Comment: Currently, 1 Identity column and A FirmaIsmi column

Comment: The thing is Message box can show the new added entry, but combobox can't

Answer (score 0):

Change your Insert query to

```
INSERT INTO FIRMATABLE (FirmaIsmi) VALUES (@CompanyName)
```

You need to include all your column names for which you are adding the VALUES.

And 
change `ExecuteScalar` to `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Add `try-catch` block and see what exception does it throws after ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: What Exception will it catch?

Comment: That's for debugging purposes. See if it throws any exception in your inserts

Comment: If `Id` is an identity column, it should not be specified in the insert statement.

Comment: Doesnt throw any exception